# Event handler inside event handler is multiplying

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I have this code

```
jQuery('#parent').on('click', jQuery('#fileInput'), function (e) {
    jQuery(e.target).attr('data-fileurl', '');
    jQuery('#parent').on('change', jQuery('#fileInput'), function (e) {
        usefulFunction(jQuery(e.target);
    }
}
```

The idea is to detect if cancel was chosen on file browse, and it succeeds at that.

The problem is if I click it again, then it will run the `.on('chance')` twice and thus run `usefulFunction`. Each click adds a change event handler. `usefulFunction` should only be run once for each time `jQuery('#fileInput')` is changed. How can I prevent this unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method instead:

```
jQuery('#parent').one('change', jQuery('#fileInput'), function (e) {
                    ^
...
```