# Editing input value using another input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As you can see I can dynamically create inputs via click of a button, I can remove them also by clicking the remove button and it will only delete the input next the remove button not every input. Taking this idea, I created an edit button and i am trying to edit input via another input. So far its almost working, when user click edit button the value of the closest input goes to the input that is on the very top of the page, I can change the value there , then click submit, the value of the initial input changed to the latest value i typed on the edit input (input on very top).

**Problem**: *do these steps to see the problem*

1. Add 3 new inputs.
2. Type 1 on the first input, 2 on second, 3 on 3rd
3. Click edit on 3rd input, value goes to the top input then type 'c' on the top input and click submit, as you can see the value on the 3rd input changed to c, good so far.
4. Now click edit on 2nd input and change the input to 'b' on the very top input and click submit. As you can see, instead of changing just the 2nd input now 2nd and 3rd input changed to 'b'.

I think its confusing the 'this' when more inputs are on the play.
how can I fix this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 100; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (wrapper.find("input").length < max_fields) {
      //max input box allowed
      $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a><button class="edit-icon">Edit</button></div>'); //add input box
    }
  });
  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
  })
  $(wrapper).on('click', '.edit-icon', function(e) {
    console.log($(this));
    e.preventDefault();
    //var remove_target = $(this).closest('div')
    var target = $(this).closest('div').find('input');
    var edit_name = target.val();
    $('.editinput').val(edit_name);
    $('.editinputsubmit').click(function() {
      console.log("click working");
      target.val($('.editinput').val());
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" class="editinput">
  <button class="editinputsubmit">submit</button>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't create an event handler inside another event handler like you're doing with `$('.editinputsubmit').click...`. The click handler will then continuously be bound over and over again on `'.editinputsubmit'`. Move that outside and use a class to specify which input you are editing. [Here is a working JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ga8d0q1o/5/).

Comment: is it possible to do a click event inside a click event without its multiplying as in my case, i am also kind of limited to using class/id hence why i used closest method

Comment: Yes, you technically can. Use `.unbind()` before `.click()` and that will work. See it in this [updated example.](https://jsfiddle.net/j7b63Lnw/3/)

Comment: It's not considered best practice but is certainly doable. Another solution, and maybe even more desirable, would be to use jQuery's `.one()` method instead of `.unbind()`. You can check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38957233/event-handler-inside-event-handler-is-multiplying) and read more about `.one()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

Comment: thanks, unbind seems to be the one that's working. one seems to need more attention. you been great help